# Show that there exists an uncountable family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that there exists an uncountable family of uncountable sets $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ such that for any $t_1,t_2\in T$, $t_1\ne t_2$ the set $X_{t_1}\cap X_{t_2}$ consists of only one element, but for any three pairwise different $t_1,t_2,t_3 \in T$ it is $X_{t_1}\cap X_{t_2} \cap X_{t_3} = \emptyset$

Any idea how to tackle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $T$ be any set, uncountable or otherwise. For $t \in T$, you want $X_t$ to contain a representative from every $X_{t'}$ for $t' \in T$, $t' \neq t$. What might be a natural way to define these elements of $X_t$, so that each element "remembers" which $t$ and $t'$ it is supposed to come from?

Comment: something like $t_{t'}$?

Comment: The subscript doesn't mean anything unless you define it to mean something. How about $\{t, t'\}$?

Comment: oh I get it now. So every two sets will have exactly one element in intersection

Comment: Yes. The element has, in itself, labelled which two $X_t$'s it's supposed to come from.

Comment: That was very smart. But what about being uncountable? We use here axiom of choice yeah?

Comment: Let $T$ be an uncountable set, for instance $T = \mathbb R$. No choice needed.

Comment: oh thats true... thank you so much